# Load mainView with shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: iphone, sdk

I am trying to load a view with the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method, but I have a problem.  When the device runs as landscape, I want to show the main view itself, and when when the device is portrait, load a custom UIView.

Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations

        if ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)|| (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))

            //doesn't show main view !!
            self.view;


        else if ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))

            //works fine ! 
            self.view = portraitView;


      return YES;

}
```

Comment: i figured out !!!!  I call my view with modal on a method .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out !!!! just call the  view with modal on a method

```
- (void) mainView {
    screenTestViewController *mv = [[screenTestViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"screenTestViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:mv animated:NO];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    // Return YES for supported orientations 

    if ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)|| (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))

        [self mainView];


.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should push your custom UIView in: `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`